# what is the relation between delegate declaration and the class in which the delegate is declared

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm very curious to know why the delegate type is visible in intellisense when I type a dot after the class name in my program file and the delegate name appears after the class's object name.
Consider the following code

```
public class DelDec
{
    public delegate void Initdel(String s);
    public Initdel Init;
}
```

If I have a instancemethod in another class

```
public class Methoddef
{
    public void process(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The message passed is" + s);
    }
}
```

Now when

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Methoddef md=new Methoddef();
        DelDec.Initdel d = md.process;
    }
}
```

My concern is demonstrated with the following images
[image]

[image]

I really want to clarify this concept.

Comment: Think of delegates as the father of events. The _tricky_ part might be the `delegate` keyword. It's like **defining** any other reference type, you would expect an inner class to appear in intellisense in the same way.

Comment: for more information on reference types read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)

Comment: I think it is common nowadays to use `Action<T,T1...>` and `Func<T1,T2...>` instead of delegates. As I think delegates, which are just the definition of a method signature, add little value

Comment: Action and Func are delegates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A delegate like this is just a nested class extending the special `System.MulticastDelegate` type and with runtime defined methods. Have a look at the IL code, produced by compiling this c# code:

```
public class C {
    public delegate void Del();
}
```

```
.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit C
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    // Nested Types
    .class nested public auto ansi sealed Del
        extends [mscorlib]System.MulticastDelegate
    {
        // Methods
        .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
            instance void .ctor (
                object 'object',
                native int 'method'
            ) runtime managed 
        {
        } // end of method Del::.ctor

        .method public hidebysig newslot virtual 
            instance void Invoke () runtime managed 
        {
        } // end of method Del::Invoke

        .method public hidebysig newslot virtual 
            instance class [mscorlib]System.IAsyncResult BeginInvoke (
                class [mscorlib]System.AsyncCallback callback,
                object 'object'
            ) runtime managed 
        {
        } // end of method Del::BeginInvoke

        .method public hidebysig newslot virtual 
            instance void EndInvoke (
                class [mscorlib]System.IAsyncResult result
            ) runtime managed 
        {
        } // end of method Del::EndInvoke

    } // end of class Del

} // end of class C
```

Note the `runtime` keyword at the method declaration, meaning that the method implementation will be provided by the runtime itself.

So what you are seeing in intellisense is just the presence of the nested type, the same should happen for any other nested type.

Comment: I saw the IL code on was able to understand the point. Appreciate your detailed reply.

Answer (score 0):

You declare method signature and name of delegate type, when you declare delegate in class. For example you know that you want call this method from you object with some signature, but you don't know which one, so you can it assign programmaticaly.

Here is code which can help you to understand.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Methoddef md=new Methoddef();
        DelDec.Initdel d = md.process; //you create variable of delegate type Initdel and asign this variable

        var obj = new DelDec();
        obj.Init = d; //assign delegate to class instance

        obj.Init("Test");

    }

    public class DelDec
    {
        //Declares a delegate for a void method that takes an string parameter.
        public delegate void Initdel(String s);
        public Initdel Init;
    }


    public class Methoddef
    {
        public void process(string s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The message passed is " + s);
        }
    }
}
```

Also good if you read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.delegate(v=vs.110).aspx

So in your first picture `DelDec.Initdel` - delagate type, in your second picrure `obj.Initdel` it is field where you can assign come method to delegate.

I hope that my answer will help you.